# Resizing a column while simultaneously animating an element from the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the code shown below, I have a post and in there is a comment button that will slide the comment box into view from the right. I'm resizing the main post element from 100% of the parent to 67% of the parent (col-lg-12 to col-lg-8). Although I'm trying to get the post element to simultaneously move with the entrance of the comment element.

Also in my fiddle i can't seem to fix how the comment slides all the way across the entire post element, rather than just a portion of it. Additionally, I can't fix the animation where it just appears rather than slides in, although the slide out animation works.

[This is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwhv12za/7/)

The code snippet below oddly doesn't work like jsfiddle does.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#comments', function(e) {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  var style = $("#comments-body-" + name).prop('class');
  if (style == "col-lg-4 hide") {
    $("#post-card-" + name).prop('class', 'col-lg-8');
    $("#comments-body-" + name).show("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $("#comments-body-" + name).prop('class', 'col-lg-4 show');
    });
  } else if (style == "col-lg-4 show") {
    $("#comments-body-" + name).hide("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $("#post-card-" + name).prop('class', 'col-lg-12');
      $("#comments-body-" + name).prop('class', 'col-lg-4 hide');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.quantity {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #dc3545;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

span #comments {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span #comments:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.divider {
  position: relative;
  Float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}

.comment-body {
  padding: 0.75rem !important;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="https://nofile.io/f/RA9FgtoD8yG/master.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


<body>
  <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <div id="notices" class="section__content section__content--p30">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="content">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="overview-wrap">
            <h2 class="title-1">Notices</h2>
            <button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newPostModal">
       <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>new post</button>
          </div><br />
          <div id="$id" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                      <strong class="card-title">
            yeet
           </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="float-right">
            <a id="remove-notice">
             <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </a>
           </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <span>
            <small><span class="float-right" id="comments" name="1">Comments <span class="quantity"><bold>1</bold></span></span>
                      </small>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div id="post-card-1" class="col-lg-12" style="position:relative;">
                      xdxddxd
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 hide" id="comments-body-1">
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                      <div style="margin-left:2vw;">
                        <div style="vertical-align:middle;">
                          <strong>Comments</strong>
                          <button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue" style="line-height:25px!important;padding:0 5px!important;float:right;"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>comment</button>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body comment-body" style="position:relative;">
                            <strong> User </strong><br/>
                            <p>
                              shfashfihgliahgal
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I hope you are still watching this question.

First, why your `show("slide"` is failed. Let's watch this code.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#button1").on("click", function() {
        // fade in. (but it doens't show due to priority problem.)
        $("#target1").fadeIn("slow", function() {
            // It shows at this timing.
            $("#target1").prop("class", "col-sm-4 show");
        });
    });
    $("#button2").on("click", function() {
        // fade in.
        $("#target2").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}

.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target1" class="col-sm-4 hide">
    Hello my name is col-sm-4! for display:none !important;
</div>

<div id="target2" class="col-sm-4 display-none">
    Hello my name is col-sm-4! for display:none;
</div>

<input type="button" class="button" value="show col-sm-4" id="button1">
<input type="button" class="button" value="show col-sm-4" id="button2">
```

Next, you want to move the entire post element.
Maybe I'm misunderstanding.
But I did fix some problem that what I thought.
Can you have a look? if anything, feel free to question me.

[For Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/cf58u2yh/)